# how can I define IST zone id in java method atZone(Zone_ID);

Tags: java, datetime

How can I define IST in the method below

```
  ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.now().atZone(zone);
```

I need value of `zone` is IST

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("GMT+05:30");
```

or

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("UTC+05:30");
```

Instead of

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
```

As it is easier to remember the time difference.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by IST. For example `ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin")` for Irish Summer Time, `ZoneId.of("Asia/Tel_Aviv")` for Israel Standard TIme or `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")` for India Standard Time.

You may use [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 0):

ZoneId z = ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("IST"));
System.out.println(z);

Output: Asia/Kolkata

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.